# MSSQL 2000 sa user account

Tags: sql-server

Everytime I try to install an application that requires the 'sa' user account for installation to allow creation of a database and admin user account I receive the following message:
Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server Connection........

When you install MSSQL 2000, is the 'sa' user enabled?  I found information on your website on how to disable and then enable an account on MSSQL 2000, but the user 'sa' can't be altered.

If not, for MSSQL 2000 'sa' user, how do I enable the account?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if your SQL Server is operating using **Windows Authentication** only. You should [enable mixed-mode authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215470(v=sql.80).aspx), and set a strong password for the 'sa' SQL user.

See also: [MS SQL 2000 authentication modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905171(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  We have tried both Windows Authentication only and Mixed mode with no success.  Do you know if the 'sa' user is enabled on MSSQL 2000 SP4 server installation while running on Windows 2003 SP1?

Comment: The 'sa' account will be enabled if you selected Mixed Mode on installation. If you installed with Windows Authentication only, and then change to Mixed Mode later, you probably need to reset the sa account password from Enterprise Manager's Security/Logins.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you choose Mixed-mode authentication (at installation or when editing the server properties in Enterprise Manager) it will automatically create and enable the sa account for you and prompt you for a password. After this if you switch to Windows Authentication and then back to mixed-mode it won't necessarily prompt you for the password.

However within Enterprise Manager you can look for the sa login by navigating to SECURITY > Logins.  From here you should see the sa login. If you right click on it you should be able to view and change the password and other access permissions. You will need to have sysadmin permissions to make any of these changes.

If you do not see the sa login you can also create it manually from the logins screen.  By default it is a member of the System Administrators server role, should have public and db_owner permissions for each database.